# ROS Answers SE migration: FlyCapture2

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi!!
I'm trying to install ccny_drivers, and was following the steps but when i do "make":

```
rosmake ccny_drivers --rosdep-install
```

I get:

pgr_camera_node.cpp:243: undefined reference to `FlyCapture2::

I have already installed FlyCapture2 SDK

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33122/flycapture2/) by [Macasten](https://answers.ros.org/users/1923/macasten/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Please check if the manifest.xml of ccny_drivers has FlyCapture2 package included.

Thanks,
Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2012-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1